# apt upgrade dpkg error wile processing (Segmentation fault)..?

Tags: dpkg

I was updating packages in raspberry pi and when I apt upgraded this error message came out.
`dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_5.1-2+b1_armhf.deb (--unpack): new bash package pre-installation script subprocess was killed by signal (Segmentation fault) update-alternatives: using /usr/share/man/man7/bash-builtins.7.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man7/builtins.7.gz (builtins.7.gz) in auto mode Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_5.1-2+b1_armhf.deb E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
I tried some error fixing with

```
dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_5.1-2+b1_armhf.deb
```

but I failed.

Answer (score 0):

The bash preinst maintainer script is a compiled program (instead of the usual shell scripts used there), to avoid having to depend on bash being present at all before it as been unpacked for the first time.

In your case it appears that program is segfaulting for some reason, so it's buggy and needs be debugged and tracked down. Your best option is to report this to the distribution you are using, ideally by providing a core file or a backtrace of the segfault.